# Why does SQL Transaction does not Rollback after connection is lost - C#?

Tags: transactions, mariadb, rollback

I'm using MariaDB 10.3.21 and I'm wondering why the Rollback is not done from the SQL-Server after the connection is lost.

I'm updating several Tables with the code below. To check if also a rollback from the server side is done after connection lost, I set a breakpoint to the objTransaction.Commit() command and after hitting it, I interrupted the network connection.

Unfortunately the update of the fields are taken over without a commit command. I assumed if a connection is lost the server will do an implicit rollback.

Any Ideas? Many Thanks!

```
    public void ExecuteSQL(List<string> pQueryList)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection objConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                objConnection.Open();

                MySqlCommand objCommand = objConnection.CreateCommand();
                MySqlTransaction objTransaction;

                // Start Transaction
                objTransaction = objConnection.BeginTransaction();

                // Must assign both transaction object and connection
                // to Command object for a pending local transaction
                objCommand.Connection = objConnection;
                objCommand.Transaction = objTransaction;

                try
                {
                    // Set autocommit = off the this session
                    //objCommand.CommandText = "SET autocommit = 0";
                    objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    foreach (string query in pQueryList)
                    {
                        // Execute the SQL Queries
                        objCommand.CommandText = query;

                        if (objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() <= 0)
                        {
                            throw (new Exception("Fehler bei ExecuteNonQuery. Anzahl der betroffenen Zeilen fehlerhaft."));
                        }
                    }

                    // Commit Transaction
                    objTransaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        // Rollback 3x versuchen (falls Netzwerkverbindung abgebrochen ist)
                        try
                        {
                            objTransaction.Rollback();
                            break;
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                        }
                    }                        
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Das speichern in die Datenbank ist fehlgeschlagen!\n\n" + ex.Message, "Fehler", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to turn off "autocommit" feature, it is enabled by default.

What is autocommit?

> A setting that causes a commit operation after each SQL statement. This mode is not recommended for working with InnoDB tables with transactions that span several statements. It can help performance for read-only transactions on InnoDB tables, where it minimizes overhead from locking and generation of undo data, especially in MySQL 5.6.4 and up. It is also appropriate for working with MyISAM tables, where transactions are not applicable.

(citation taken from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_autocommit)

Read here about autocommit, and how to turn it off:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html

Comment: As you see in my code I have already checked to turn off the "autocommit" feature (objCommand.CommandText = "SET autocommit = 0";), but this will also not work.

Comment: @Marco how about checking it manually first in some SQL editor like DBeaver, try some different syntaxes (I can see here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-transactions-and-isolation-levels-for-sql-server-users/ that there is more than one), like: SET SESSION autocommit := 0;

Comment: I could solve the problem. The storage engine was set to MyISAM which has no support for transactions. I changed it to InnoDB and it works. ([link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-engines.html). Thanks psychoboi111 for the tip with the SQL Editor. HeidiSQL gives me the right tip with the engine!

Comment: @Marco och, I thought about mentioning the storage engine, but then I thought that default for MariaDB is InnoDB. Anyway, no problem :)